# T-SQL if date is greater or equal to this date then return x if not return y

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, field, lookup

I have a transaction date and need to return a field from another table.

```
Table A  Visit    Bill     Transaction Date
          1         1          12/20/2016
```

I have another table I need to return a code if the code date is after the Transaction Date.

```
Table B   Bill   CodeID  Effective Code Date         Code
           1        A        9/1/2015                  ABCDE
           1        B        9/1/2015                  FGHI 
           1        C        9/1/2015                  JKLM
           1        A        10/01/2016                ZQMOP
           1        B        10/01/2016                XYZNP
           1        C        10/01/2016                EFGHI
```

How do I get this result?

```
 Vist   Bill  TransactionDate   CodeID     Code
 1       1       12/20/2016      A        ZQMOP
 1       1       12/20/2016      B        XYZNP
 1       1       12/20/2016      C        EFGHI
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  From your example above, none of it should be returned since none of them is after Transaction Date.

Comment: @Eric sorry, I meant I need to return the CodeID and code with the effective date closest to the transaction date. Example: since the transaction date is 12/20/2016, I I need the 10/01/2016 codes. If the transaction date was 9/2/2015, I need to return the codes with the effective date 9/1/2015. I haven't tried anything yet. I don't have a code.

Comment: Your first table; does it just contain a single value? Depending on what else is in that table, various answers to your question might yield unexpected numbers of rows.

Comment: @Xedni Table A is the same. Table B I forgot to add the bill. I've added it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach, but there are others that come to mind (like using `row_number`)

First two CTEs are just setting up your data. Then the query basically pulls everything for `10/01/2016`. That date is determined by the subquery which selects the `max(b.EffectiveCodeDate)` which is strictly less than the transaction date for that bill.

```
;with a as
(
    select visit = 1, bill = 1, transactiondate = cast('12/20/2016' as date)
), b (Bill, CodeId, EffectiveCodeDate, Code) as
(
              select 1, 'A', cast('9/1/2015' as date),'ABCDE'
    union all select 1, 'B', '9/1/2015','FGHI' 
    union all select 1, 'C', '9/1/2015','JKLM'
    union all select 1, 'A', '10/01/2016','ZQMOP'
    union all select 1, 'B', '10/01/2016','XYZNP'
    union all select 1, 'C', '10/01/2016','EFGHI' 
)
select *
from b
where b.EffectiveCodeDate = 
    (
        select max(b.EffectiveCodeDate)
        from b
        inner join a
            on a.Bill = b.Bill
            and b.EffectiveCodeDate < a.TransactionDate
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below query works

**Sample Data:**

```
create table #A (Visit int, Bill int, [Transaction Date] date)
insert into #A values (1, 1, '12/20/2016')

create table #B (Bill int, CodeID char(1),  [Effective Code Date] date, Code varchar(10))
insert into #B values
(1, 'A', '9/1/2015'  , 'ABCDE'),
(1, 'B', '9/1/2015'  , 'FGHI' ),
(1, 'C', '9/1/2015'  , 'JKLM' ),
(1, 'A', '10/01/2016', 'ZQMOP'),
(1, 'B', '10/01/2016', 'XYZNP'),
(1, 'C', '10/01/2016', 'EFGHI')
```

**Query:**

```
;with ct as (
    select *
    , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Bill, CodeID order by [Effective Code Date] desc) RN
    from #B
)
select #A.*, ct.CodeID, ct.Code
from #A 
    inner join ct on ct.Bill = #A.Bill and ct.RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work it out :

```
DECLARE @MinimumDiffrence int = (select Min(ABS(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,transaction_date,Effective_Code_Date))) 
                                from A inner join B on A.Bill=B.Bill)
select * 
from A
inner join B 
on A.Bill = B.Bill
where ABS(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,transaction_date,Effective_Code_Date)) = @MinimumDiffrence
```

There must be a way to do this with just 1 query and I will work on to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
create table #A (Visit int, Bill int, [Transaction Date] date)
insert into #A values (1, 1, '12/20/2016')

create table #B (Bill int, CodeID char(1), 
 [Effective Code Date] date, Code varchar(10))
insert into #B values
(1, 'A', '9/1/2015'  , 'ABCDE'),
(1, 'B', '9/1/2015'  , 'FGHI' ),
(1, 'C', '9/1/2015'  , 'JKLM' ),
(1, 'A', '10/01/2016', 'ZQMOP'),
(1, 'B', '10/01/2016', 'XYZNP'),
(1, 'C', '10/01/2016', 'EFGHI')

select * from
#A a 
    inner join #B b on b.Bill = a.Bill 
 where DATEDIFF(day,[Effective Code Date],[Transaction Date]) =
(
select min(DATEDIFF(day,[Effective Code Date],[Transaction Date])) MinDiff
from #A a 
    inner join #B b on b.Bill = a.Bill 

) 

    drop table #A
    drop table #B
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach, using `CROSS APPLY` comes closest to the *description* of the problem you want to solve:

```
declare @ta table (Visit int not null, Bill int not null, TransactionDate date not null)
insert into @ta (Visit,Bill,TransactionDate) values
(1,1,'20161220')

declare @tb table (Bill int not null, CodeID char(1) not null, 
                   EffectiveCodeDate date not null, Code varchar(5) not null)
insert into @tb (Bill,CodeID,EffectiveCodeDate,Code) values
(1,'A','20150901','ABCDE'),
(1,'B','20150901','FGHI'),
(1,'C','20150901','JKLM'),
(1,'A','20161001','ZQMOP'),
(1,'B','20161001','XYZNP'),
(1,'C','20161001','EFGHI')

select
    *
from
    @ta a
        cross apply
    (select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CodeID ORDER by EffectiveCodeDate desc) as rn
    from @tb b
    where
        b.Bill = a.Bill and
        b.EffectiveCodeDate < a.TransactionDate) p
where
    rn = 1
```

That is, for each row in table B, and for each distinct `CodeID` value, we want to select the latest row which predates the `TransactionDate` from table A.

Result:

```
Visit       Bill        TransactionDate Bill        CodeID EffectiveCodeDate Code  rn
----------- ----------- --------------- ----------- ------ ----------------- ----- --------------------
1           1           2016-12-20      1           A      2016-10-01        ZQMOP 1
1           1           2016-12-20      1           B      2016-10-01        XYZNP 1
1           1           2016-12-20      1           C      2016-10-01        EFGHI 1
```

(Left as an exercise to trim the result set down to just the columns you need)